# .sas file contains var names, values are stored in text file

Tags: pandas, sas, xlsx, txt

I have a .sas file containing column locators (@ sign, I guess) and the variable name associated with that locator. These are the first two lines of code (I managed to open it in STATA):

```
   @18   PROFAM     $6.         /*Progressivo famiglia univoco a livello indagine*/                                                                                                                  
   @24   PROIND     $2.         /*Progressivo individuo nell'ambito della famiglia*/
```

Besides, I have a dataset that I cannot parse and is both in .txt file and in a file with no extension (I use a mac and could not find a reason for this).

How can I run the .sas file through the text and .? files and store the full dataset in .xlsx format so that I can easily import it into pandas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like you are showing a couple of lines from middle of a single statement in a SAS program.  Reading between the lines in your post it sounds like you want help is understanding how to translate that code so you will know how to read the associated data file?  Go to the SAS website and read about the syntax of the INPUT statement.  Then figure out how to read a fixed length text file with whatever tool your want to use, python, Excel, etc.

Comment: You have a text file and the file you've shown explains the layout. You can use that information, manually to code your import/parsing in Python. It seems like it's a fixed width layout so standard import procedures won't work.I'm assuming you don't have SAS.

Comment: @Reeza Yes, I do not have SAS. Is it really the only option to import manually the dataset into python? The only alternative I came up with is to import the text file in excel and then parse the whole thing from the import window.

Comment: I would not recommend using Excel. You'll have to use the GUI and then manually find each delimiter and it's very easy to make a mistake eyeballing it. You have file specifications, you could likely parse that into something Python could understand but either way, yes, you have to manually specify the file specifications for a fixed width file. It's annoying and tedious but not particularly difficult by any means.

Comment: It's also really the only way to ensure you import the data 100% correctly with these types of files.